# Second order equation always positive with delta < 0

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have the following equation

$7p^2-3p+1>0$

Delta is negative but the equation should always be positive, how can I notice the latter observation? I mean: I've been solving this for half an hour (checking if I had made a mistake) without success and then noticed that the equation is always positive, how can I determine if an equation is always positive when the delta is <0? Is there any rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the discriminant ($\Delta$) of the quadratic is negative then it always keeps the same sign. As for $p = 0$ it is positive then...